# How to pass and read arguments to a lua program?

Tags: lua

Equivalent to `main(int argc, char*argv[])` of C. For example: `./foo.lua -a -b` how do I read `-a` and `-b` from `foo.lua` program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Command line arguments are in the global table `arg`. See [here](http://torch5.sourceforge.net/manual/LuaManual-6.html) for details. Since there is no argparse/optparse library you will need to handle the logic for short and long switches yourself.

Answer (score 7):

The command line arguments are also available as real arguments to the script, which are vararg functions. So you can do:

```
local x,y,z = ...
```

If you need to loop over the command line arguments, use the `arg` table.

Comment: See also [Command Line Parsing](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CommandLineParsing) in the Lua wiki.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent [argparse](https://github.com/mpeterv/argparse) library.
Docs are here: http://argparse.readthedocs.io/en/stable/